# using sharepoint webservice in LDAP-AD

Tags: web-services

I have created an JSP WEB application with LDAP-AD Authentication, and im accessing sharepoint 2010 document library using sharepoint webservices.
Here, my problem is i need to connect my .net web application to sharepoint 2010 site.
Please advise me to do that.How can i redirect to sharepoint site without asking(single sign on) or one time login process.

Thanks and Regards
Dekui

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Rephrase if you're expecting valid answers.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "Connect your .Net application to SharePoint"? Are you trying to access SharePoint info (list etc) from your .Net app?